# Will Email sent from a 3rd Party SMTP service get classified spam?

Tags: smtp

I have a web application that I developed. I was originally using the Google Apps smtp servers for the outbound emails generated from the application for user notifications.  As use increased Google Apps began to throttle the outbound emails. So I am considering using a 3rd party SMTP service, but if I send the emails using a from address with my domain name won't the emails be marked as spam?

I considered making a low priority MX record for the relay service but these service do not use static IP's. So I am not sure about the concept for this deployment.

How should this be setup so emails can be from my sites domain but the emails nt be caught in spam because the are considered spoofed?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any third-party SMTP will give you instructions on flagging them as a valid sender for your domain via SPF and DKIM records. SPF in particular allows you to say "this server/service is allowed to pose as me".

Comment: Just to be clear, there's no impersonation involved. The SPF record says "this server is allowed to send email for my domain.".

Comment: Ahhh fantastic this is exactly what I was wondering